# how to create post method

Tags: json, web-services, post

I am currently working on activiti-rest
so I try to create the methods post, put, delete ....
my problem arises when i create the post method, i want to create a user with post

here is part of my code

```
// The user we want to create in JSON format

    String user = "{\" id \ ": \" id \ ", \" firstName \ ": \" getFirstname1 () \ ", \" lastName \ ": \" lastName \ ", \" email \ ": \ "email \", \ "password \": \ "lastName \"} ";
```

it shows me in the database firstname ...... me I want to create a user object with the values ​​that I enter in my form how to solve this problem

I am a beginner

Comment: What is the problem you're having? What is your question?

Comment: the parameters id ,, name ........ I do not want to fix them in the code I want to take the data of the form

Answer (score 0):

Stringifying the JSON data is most likely the culprit. You have to find a way to send the data Encoded, then when you get a request to POST, you have to decode the data so that it reads it properly.

Comment: the parameters id ,, name ........ I do not want to fix them in the code I want to take the data of the form